# Constructing a nested if statement

Tags: excel, if-statement, nested

I am having a little trouble constructing a nested if statement.

My issue is that I need to fill in a cell with a presenter name, however, there are three options. I have constructed an if statement that will look in two cells for text and pull the second word from them.

However what I also want to happen is that if either of the two cells is empty it will return `TBD`.

My existing formula is:

```
=IF(ISTEXT(I2),get_word(I2,2),get_word(J2,2))
```

I am trying to add to this to do the following:

```
=IF(ISTEXT(I2),get_word(I2,2),get_word(J2,2),if(j2="",I2=""),TBD)
```

But this is proving ineffective.
Can anyone point me in the right direction to solve this?

Comment: I think the `,TBD` should be inside the parens to their left.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's better to check for blanks first?

```
=IF(OR(J2="",I2=""),"TBD", IF(ISTEXT(I2),get_word(I2,2),get_word(J2,2)))
```

And if neither are blank, do what was being done before.

Answer (score 0):

Are columns I and J First and last name?

Just trying to build your statement and not sure what the I and J column signify? If you can share a table with me I might be able to help construct what you need.